# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.Util.report(Ljava/lang/String;)V when initializing OpenSaml

Tags: java, slf4j, nosuchmethoderror, opensaml

I'm using OpenSaml in my maven project. When I try to initialize OpenSaml, using a variation of the    DefaultBootstrap    class, I get the following stacktrace:

```
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.Util.report(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.<clinit>(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:47)
    org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:42)
    org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:73)
    org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:103)
    org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.<init>(XMLConfigurator.java:56)
    org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.<init>(XMLConfigurator.java:73)
```

I've tried to do mvn dependency:tree to figure out from where the mismatched version of SLF4J jar is being loaded from. I've also tried passing the -verbose option to Java in mvn.bat. Neither of these options helped. I've tried removing the dependencies in my pom.xml one by one. Again, no luck. If someone could throw some light on how to find the culprit jar or how to solve this error, I'd be grateful.

Comment: can you paste the part of your pom with the slf4j / log4j dependencies? Did you check the slf4j [buglist](http://bugzilla.slf4j.org)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would wager that you have slf4j-api.jar version 1.5.0 or earlier in your class path whereas the version of log4j-over-slf4j.jar has a later version.

Comment: You are absolutely right. One of my custom jars was loading slf4j-api version 1.5.0 jar. OpenSaml was loading 4 slf4j jars with version 1.6.0. When I tried to exclude the 1.5.0 slf4j jars from my custom jar, I ran into more issues. I need to do more research to understand what those issues are. However, once I excluded the 1.6.0 slf4j jars from OpenSaml, things started working fine. mvn dependency:tree helped me understand this issue better. Thanks for taking the time to comment.

Comment: Do not exclude. Instead, use maven's proximity rule for artifact resolution. Dependencies declared in the current project override declarations made by other components, i.e by the pom.xml files of your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar issue. After a lot of exploring and debugging I found that the log4j lib was not compatible. My Custom build jar had hbase async client that required log4j-1.2.12 or higher.